# hashsum is not available- unable to get source of package

Tags: apt, software-installation, debian, snapshot

I want to get the source of package wirehshark for year 2009. I am doing that by editing `source.list` according to Debian snapshot information. After doing `sudo apt-get update`. I tried:

```
sudo apt-get source wireshark
--skipped downloading of file wireshark....dsc as requested hashsum is not available for authentication<br>
--skipped downloading of file wireshark....gz as requested hashsum is not available for authentication<br>
--skipped downloading of file wireshark....diff.gz as requested hashsum is not available for authentication<br>
Need to get 0B of source archive.
```

Basically if am trying to get the source of any packages using debian snapshot of year 2009.. i am getting this error. how to solve this? please give suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the snapshot also on the [snapshot webpage](https://snapshot.debian.org/package/wireshark/). Here you will 
find tar.gz (source) files.

In the year 2009 it was the **1.2 version**.

Comment: Ok.. this is a direct download. As debian maintains snapshots from march 2005. If i want to download version of 2005 then which folder is it? like i tried the last one and that is of year 2006-07 but not of 2005. How can i get source of 2005? and how can i get source of files older than 2005?